# Network Flair uses Stack Overflow profile photo on all sites

Tags: bug, profile-picture, combined-flair

I recently changed my profile picture and saved it only to Stack Overflow.

I included my flair in my profile page in all SE sites.

When I checked my SO profile page, I saw that the flair is using my SO profile picture. I think it is somewhat like badges (taken from the current site). But when I checked my MSE profile, the flair is also using the profile picture from my Stack Overflow account.

This is my Stack Overflow profile picture:

[image]

This is my network profile picture:

[image]

And this is my network flair:

[image]

Code for my network flair:

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2824081.png?theme=clean
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it uses the avatar of your site where you have the highest reputation.

Comment: I am not sure with that. may be you are right. But what I think is it should use the profile picture in MSE for network flair. I changed the SO pic for fun but I don't want it to appear in my website where I am using network flair

Comment: @Bart I don't think so, consider [Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=accounts) network profile, in [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) he have the highest reputation, but the Network Profile avatar is from his [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) profile.